# Inserting CSS in top navigation bar

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, css, html

I would like to alter the look of the top navigation bar, but I am not sure how to insert the CSS into the page.  I know all the elements' class names, but changing their default styles seems to be eluding me.  I would like to avoid javascript if possible, because we are using the same top navigation bar across all the sub-sites.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, put all the styles in a css file and upload it to the Site Assets library, then you can reference it in couple of ways to do this:

Option 1:

- Site Settings ==> Under Look and Feel ==> Master Page ==> Alternate CSS URL and enter the URL to your custom css file, like this `/SiteAssets/CSS/styles.css`

Option 2:

- Edit your master page (always make a backup before you modify master pages), and insert the link to your custom after SharePoint main/default css files

Comment: Good Luck! Please mark it as answer if it works!!

Comment: I am sorry.  Something odd is happening with my SharePoint Designer and it won't let me log in.  As soon as I can attempt the changes I will update.

Comment: I used Option 1 and it worked great.  Also learned something interesting about how SharePoint works.  Thanks Ahmed.

Comment: Awesome! Glad that worked..